# How to handle multiple errors for sql

Tags: python, flask, error-handling

I'm trying to build an Http API with flask and sqlite. The get url gets 2 parameters (**username** and **password**). Here is the code:

```
def query_user():
    try:
        sqlite_service = SQLiteService()
        sqlite_service.deduct_points()
        username = request.args.get("Username", default=None, type=str)
        password = request.args.get("Password", default=None, type=str)

        if username is not None and password is not None:
            successful, error_message, code = sqlite_service.query_user(username=username, password=password)
            return jsonify(Successful=successful, Error_message=error_message), code
        else:
            if username is None and password is None:
                return jsonify(Successful=False, Error_message="Please enter a username and a password!"), 400
            elif username is None:
                return jsonify(Successful=False, Error_message="Please enter a username!"), 400
            elif password is None:
                return jsonify(Successful=False, Error_message="Please enter a password!"), 400
            else:
                return jsonify(Successful=False, Error_message="Error in app.query_user!"), 400
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify(
            Successful=False,
            Error_message="Error (" + str(e.__class__) + ") in app.query_user: " + str(e.args)
        ), 400
```

In SQLiteService:

```
def query_user(self, username: str, password: str) -> Tuple[bool, str, int]:
        try:
            self._cursor.execute(
                """
                SELECT UserID, Password 
                FROM User 
                WHERE Username=?
                """,
                (username,)
            )
            result = self._cursor.fetchone()
            if result[0] is not None:
                if result[1] == password:
                    return True, list(result)[0], 200    #list(result)[0] is userID
                else:
                    return False, "Password " + password + " is incorrect.", 400
            else:
                return False, "No user " + username + " exists.", 400
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            return False, "Error in SQLiteService.query_user: " + str(e.__class__) + ": " + str(e.args) + ".", 400
```

I'm trying to handle the case where the password is incorrect (it has to show "Password is incorrect.") but i always get **"Error_message": "Error (<class 'TypeError'>) in app.query_user: ("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable",)"**

Comment: At what line number is this error message happening? Can you give a full stack-trace?

Comment: @shashwat it comes from `Error_message="Error (" + str(e.__class__) + ") in app.query_user: " + str(e.args)`

Comment: I'd suggest removing the try/except block, so you can get more context on where the error is happening. That should give the complete stack trace as well

Comment: Which block? in SQLiteService?

Comment: No, the first file.

Comment: Basically, when you catch an error, you're limiting the amount of information the error has to whatever you're printing. Here you're only printing the class and the args. We want to know the line number where it's failing as well. If you remove the try/catch block, it'll fail and display the entire stacktrace including the line number, and potentially even the variable name. That will help us debug

Comment: @shashwat alright thanks!